# Styling WordPress's wp_link_pages()

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm using `wp_link_pages()` to display pagination, Which looks like:

```
1
<a href="/2">2</a>
<a href="/3">3</a>
<a href="/4">4</a>
```

Since this just returns a formatted html string like the above, I find it hard to wrap the current page number in a span to look something like:

```
<span class="current">1</span>
<a href="/2">2</a>
<a href="/3">3</a>
<a href="/4">4</a>
```

How to wrap a number surrounded with spaces (sometimes nothing or even `<a>` tags) in a span tag?

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in functions.php

```
function custom_wp_link_pages( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'before' => '<p id="post-pagination">' . __( 'Pages:' ), 
        'after' => '</p>',`enter code here`
        'text_before' => '',
        'text_after' => '',
        'next_or_number' => 'number', 
        'nextpagelink' => __( 'Next page' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
        'pagelink' => '%',
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $r = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $r );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;

    $output = '';
    if ( $multipage ) {
        if ( 'number' == $next_or_number ) {
            $output .= $before;
            for ( $i = 1; $i < ( $numpages + 1 ); $i = $i + 1 ) {
                $j = str_replace( '%', $i, $pagelink );
                $output .= ' ';
                if ( $i != $page || ( ( ! $more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ) )
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                else
                    $output .= '<span class="current-post-page">';

                $output .= $text_before . $j . $text_after;
                if ( $i != $page || ( ( ! $more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ) )
                    $output .= '</a>';
                else
                    $output .= '</span>';
            }
            $output .= $after;
        } else {
            if ( $more ) {
                $output .= $before;
                $i = $page - 1;
                if ( $i && $more ) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                    $output .= $text_before . $previouspagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
                }
                $i = $page + 1;
                if ( $i <= $numpages && $more ) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page( $i );
                    $output .= $text_before . $nextpagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
                }
                $output .= $after;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;

    return $output;
}
```

And call with `custom_wp_link_pages()`

Source: http://bavotasan.com/2012/a-better-wp_link_pages-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

**Why regex as tag ?**

You need to use something like:

**Page-links in Paragraph Tags**

```
<?php wp_link_pages('before=<p>&after=</p>&next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?>
```

Displays page-links wrapped in paragraph tags.

**Page-links in DIV**

```
<?php wp_link_pages('before=<div id="page-links">&after=</div>'); ?>
```

Displays page-links in DIV for CSS reference as `<div id="page-links">`.

Docs reference : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages